# Octave Code for Minimum and Max and finding index

Tags: indexing, max, row, octave, minimum

***Hello everyone,***
I've been trying to code this program to find the max and min values in a **row vector** and I had a problem with assigning their dimension *indexes* 
I can't figure out what's wrong
C and D always show to be "**1**"
i'm a beginner can you please help me

```
function [low,high,index1,index2] = Q1(x)
low = x(1);
high = x(1);
  index1 = x(1,2);
  index2 = x(1,2);
    for i = 2:length(x),
        if x(i) < low,
            low = x(i);
        index1 = find(low);
        elseif x(i) > high,

        high = x(i);
    index2 = find(high);

endif;
    endfor;
endfunction
```

Comment: If `low` is a scalar, then `find(low)` will always return 1, unless `low` is 0, in which case it returns an empty array. You need to do `index1=i`, same for the other one.

Comment: what do you intend to do with `x(1,2)` ? If x is a vector, it should be addressed always with a single index as in `x(i)`. In general it is always better to show a set of data and the expected result

Comment: I want index1 and index2 to be an output as (1,2) matrix indicating the location of the values of Low and High variables.

Comment: I did the     index1=i     thing and nothing changed.

Comment: What are "C and D" you mention in the question? You have no C and D there.  Also, please provide a sample input x and the outputs [low, high, index1, index2] you would expect from that set.

Comment: is there a reason you don't just use the min and max functions, which can also return the index location of the min and max values? see `help min` and `help max`

Comment: @NickJ My assignment is to do so without using min and max

Comment: @NickJ I expect to a = "one number"   b= "one number "  c="two numbers "   d="two numbers"    c and d are supposed to be reference to row number and column number.

Comment: OK, your reference to a b c d are still very unclear. Row number and column number of what? A b c d don't appear at all in your question or code in any meaningful way.

Comment: here is the assignment : Write an Octave program that will determine the minimum and maximum value of an array along with the locations of minimum and maximum values. you may assume the array will be a row vector and there will only be a single instance for the maximum and minimum values. DO NOT use built in min and max to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `index1` and `index2` should start with 1 as `low` and `high` start with element `x(1)`. When you detect a condition assign `x(i)` to the value and `i` to the `relative index`.

```
function [low,high,index1,index2] = Q1(x)
low = x(1);
high = x(1);
index1 = 1;
index2 = 1;
    for i = 2:length(x),
        if (x(i) < low)
            low = x(i);
            index1 = i;
        elseif (x(i) > high)
            high = x(i);
            index2 = i;
        endif
    endfor;
endfunction
```

using random data for testing

```
octave:1> x=rand(10,1)
x =

   0.90588
   0.20695
   0.46777
   0.67169
   0.69547
   0.24960
   0.16570
   0.62231
   0.18489
   0.36467

octave:2> Q1(x)
ans =  0.16570
octave:3> [low,high,index_low,index_high]=Q1(x)
low =  0.16570
high =  0.90588
index_low =  7
index_high =  1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what I need.

Comment: Than you should accept the answer ;-) . Question: which course are you following ?

Comment: sorry .. new at this :D  . MATLAB and Octave for Beginners
EPFLx on EDX platform.

Comment: May be you can find useful the material of the Professor Andreas Stahel at BFH https://web.sha1.bfh.science/    https://web.sha1.bfh.science/Labs/PWF/Documentation/OctaveAtBFH.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It appears your function could be accomplished very quickly without loops using the `min` and `max` functions.  Assuming `x` is a row vection:

```
>> x = [8 4 9 7 6 4 2 3 5 6] 
x =
   8   4   9   7   6   4   2   3   5   6

>> [min_x, min_x_loc] = min (x)
min_x =  2
min_x_loc =  7

>> [max_x, max_x_loc] = max (x)
max_x =  9
max_x_loc =  3
```

if you want to put it in a single function, using your notation:

```
function [low, high, index1, index2] = Q1(x)
  [low, index1] = min (x);
  [high, index2] = max (x);
end
```

(not necessary, but using `end` instead of `endfuntion` does retain matlab compatibility)

Comment: my job is to find the minimum and maximum values without using the built-in operations. I also has to show the index number of this value which consists of two numbers ( number of row      number of column)

Comment: You said the input is a row vector. So row will always be 1.